# What's the topic of 「彼の本は赤いです。」?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-の

> 彼の本は赤いです。

His book is red. What is the topic? Is it him or the color red, since 赤い is after the は?

Answer (score 8):

In Japanese, particles come *after* the things they mark:

> **彼の本は**赤いです。

The topic is the entire phrase 彼の本.

Answer (score 4):

Topic is 彼の本 ("his book") and is clearly marked by the following topic particle は.